# NPM downgrade to latest stable

Tags: node.js

I'm having some problems ([similar to these, and others](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/6047)) with beta npm (2.0.0-beta.0). It comes with latest node, and I can't seem be able to downgrade it to latest stable (1.4.26).

I've tried

> foobar@computer:/var/www/webapp$ sudo npm install npm@1.4.26 -g
>   npm WARN engine npm@1.4.26: wanted: {"node":">=0.8","npm":"1"} (current: {"node":"0.10.31","npm":"2.0.0-beta.0"})
>   /home/foobar/npm/bin/npm -> /home/foobar/npm/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js
>   npm@1.4.26 /home/foobar/npm/lib/node_modules/npm
>
> foobar@computer:/var/www/webapp$ npm -v
>   2.0.0-beta.0

(sudoless as well, but EACCESS)
"npm update npm -g" still returns me beta release. I've tried googling, but hitting the wrong keywords as it seems (all about updating modules, not npm itself) Please help